# Paging with category page

Tags: paginate-links

I have created my category.php to display all the posts (i am using custom post) in the category.

By default, it's displaying 10 entries, and when i scroll down, i wanna fetch the next 10 entries with jquery infinite scroll.
The problem is when i added the following lines to my template, it shows the link(href) to "/category/category_name/page/2" which returns 404.

```
<?php if($loop->max_num_pages > 1) : ?>
<nav id="page-nav" class="navigation" role="navigation">
    <?php previous_posts_link('≪ Previous', $loop->max_num_pages); ?>
    <?php next_posts_link('More ≫', $loop->max_num_pages); ?>
</nav>
<?php endif; ?>
```

How should i set my link (href) so that it fetch the next 10 entries in the same category?

Thank you.

Comment: Please **edit your question** to include your **custom query parameters**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`category.php` is the [main category archive template file](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Category_display), which is auto-magically loaded by WordPress for category archives. In that case, use the [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) hook to alter the main query for this page and you shouldn't have trouble with the pagination.

```
function pregp_wpse_100602($qry) {
  if (is_category() && is_main_query()) {
    // no idea what conditions you want, but below is a sample
    // $qry->set('posts_per_page',5);
  }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','pregp_wpse_100602');
```

As is, you've created a second loop-- `$loop->`-- for the page. The pagination functions do not work well when you do that. Those functions depend on the *main* query, which you are not using. I believe that is the root of the problem.

### Related

[Wordpress pagination on custom script](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/92520/wordpress-pagination-on-custom-script/92559#92559)
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/77545/21376

Comment: Also: I think the OP would want something like `query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'cpt-slug' ) );`, where `'cpt-slug'` is the slug passed to `register_post_type()`. This will add the CPT to the category query.

Comment: @ChipBennett : Yes, I am guessing something like that as well but I am not really sure. That does _seem_ to be the point of this, though the wisdom of hijacking the entire category archive is questionable.

Comment: The OP needs to post the current **custom query parameters**, so we can understand what is currently being done (the *wisdom* of that action may or may not be relevant :) ).

Comment: thanks for the answers. I realized that there is nothing wrong with the href as showned on the question, the problem is i am using custom post type, which shows 404 when it fetch the link custom_post_type/page/2 , and i found this plugin which solved my problem!

Custom Post Type Category Pagination Fix